Starship IFT-4: flashes below hypersonic speed
In the camera feed, we see occasional bright flashes well after the ship has ceased being hypersonic.
Then at 700km/h the flashes suddenly increase to the point that it looks as if the ship has caught fire.







Then at around 400km/h the "fire" went out.
Then when the flip maneuver began, the "fire" reignited, and burned until landing.
What's going on here?

Can you add a video link and time stamps, so we can see what you are referring to?

Starship has several vent ports under its skirt where it vents excess methane and oxygen. It is quite likely that the flashes are the vented methane igniting when it comes into contact with the still-hot structure of Starship.

Rather than 'excess' possibly more 'boiled by soak through heat from re-entry', especially if similar damage to the thermal protective system has present on the belly of the vehicle letting more heat reach the tanks.
